# Blocking access the contents(jsp files) outside WEB_INF

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

I have few folder just outside WEB-INF folder and those folders contains jsp files.

```
Sample Directory structure: 
-WEB-INF
-DirA
  -a.jsp
  -b.jsp
-DirB
 -c.jsp
 -d.jsp
```

How to block the user accessing the static files (jsps) outside the WEB-INF folder in websphare 8 sever?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify security-constraints in your web.xml.  A good tutorial for web app security can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html

Basically, you will need something like this in your web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
  <display-name>SecurityConstraintForDirA</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>DirAResources</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/DirA/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>dirAUsers</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Hope this helps, Andy

Comment: Thanks. I checked this one earlier. Since i have multiple folders outside WEB-INF directory..If i want to use this way, I need to add each and every folders in the web.xml. Is there any other ways to block it in websphare settings?

Comment: This link may also be useful:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1303_lansche/1303_lansche.html

Note that you can specify multiple url patterns in a security constraint - so you could have one security constraint for all your directories (i.e. /*) or some subset (i.e. /DirA, /DirB, /DirC).

I'm not aware of any WebSphere-specific way to secure multiple directories.